How to use eslint flat config for vue with typescript?
I am trying to upgrade to eslint 9 on an existing project.
I use vue3 and typescript 5 as well as prettier.
The issue lies with the new flat config which I haven't used before. I have figured it out that I should be using a different plugin, specifically this one https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/, but it only seems to serve javascript .vue files and not typescript ones.
How can I write eslint.config.js in order to work with vue3, typescript and eslint 9 ?
This is what I have tried:
import eslint from "@eslint/js";
import tseslint from "typescript-eslint";
import pluginVue from "eslint-plugin-vue";
import eslintConfigPrettier from "eslint-config-prettier";

export default tseslint.config(
  {
    ignores: ["dist/**", "node_modules/**", "**/cypress/**", "html/", "coverage/"],
    files: ["**/*.vue", "**/*.js", "**/*.ts", "**/*.jsx", "**/*.tsx"],
    languageOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 2020,
    },
  },
  eslint.configs.recommended,
  {
    plugins: {
      "@typescript-eslint": tseslint.plugin,
    },
    languageOptions: {
      parser: tseslint.parser,
      parserOptions: {
        project: true,
      },
    },
  },
  ...pluginVue.configs["flat/recommended"],
  ...pluginVue.configs["flat/strongly-recommended"],
  ...pluginVue.configs["flat/essential"],
  {
    rules: {
      "vue/match-component-import-name": "warn",
      "vue/match-component-file-name": [
        "error",
        {
          extensions: ["vue"],
          shouldMatchCase: true,
        },
      ],
      "vue/component-definition-name-casing": ["error", "PascalCase"],
      "vue/block-tag-newline": [
        "warn",
        {
          singleline: "always",
          multiline: "always",
          maxEmptyLines: 0,
        },
      ],
      "vue/html-self-closing": [
        "error",
        {
          html: {
            void: "always",
            normal: "never",
            component: "always",
          },
          svg: "always",
          math: "always",
        },
      ],
      "vue/require-default-prop": "off",
    },
  },
  eslintConfigPrettier
);


I suggest https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-config-typescript/issues/76#issuecomment-2051234597 as a resource for this. With that and https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-flat-gitignore I was able to get my setup eslinting reasonably, although prettier-eslint still didn't work because of https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint/issues/947.

It look me hours to come up with this (works as of now!)
I have removed all the things that didn't seem to be doing anything, so this is as barebones as possible for general use.  Name this eslint.config.js.  I put it in the root of my monorepo, and plan to forget about it as much as possible.
import eslintJs from '@eslint/js'
import tsEslint from 'typescript-eslint'
import vueParser from 'vue-eslint-parser'
import pluginVue from 'eslint-plugin-vue'

export default [
    {
        //---- GLOBAL IGNORES
        // note folders can only be ignored at the global level, per-cfg you must do: '**/dist/**/*'
        ignores: [
            '**/dist/',
            '**/vendor/',
        ],
    },
    // general defaults
    eslintJs.configs['recommended'],
    // general
    {
        files: ['**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,vue}'],
        languageOptions: {
            ecmaVersion: 'latest',
            sourceType: 'module',
        },
        rules: {},
    },

    // chosen typescript defaults - could not get this working
    // ...tsEslint.configs['recommended'],
    // typescript
    {
        files: ['**/*.{ts,tsx,vue}'],
        languageOptions: {
            parser: tsEslint.parser,
        },
    },

    // chosen vue defaults
    ...pluginVue.configs['flat/essential'],
    // vue
    {
        files: ['**/*.vue'],
        languageOptions: {
            parser: vueParser,
            parserOptions: {
                parser: tsEslint.parser,  // parse TS inside VUE
            },
        },
    },
]


the hint with the 'ignores' was very important. Thanks for that. I'ts not obvious if you read the docs for eslint, then typescript-eslint then for eslint-plugin-vue. To clarify even more: the 'ignores' directive should come first - before any other config

I tried your solution with your setup + default vite/vue installation. However it does not lint/mark errors in vue or TS files. Does this still work for you or do you have any other changes?
